# Custom functions in Processing Language

Tags: java, processing

doing some uni work on 'Processing' Programming language (a form of java).

So my question is **'Write a function called twoNumbers(int a,int b) which takes in two parameters a and b.  If a is greater than b, then the two numbers are added together and the string 'the sum of a and b is sum' is displayed in the console window, where a and b and the sum are the values of a, b and their sum.  Finally, the function should return the sum.'**

..soo here is my attempt at the code, if I put (int a,int b) after the customer function, it just says that my other int a = number, is a duplicate, which is true, but im not sure how I am ment to give a and b a number without it thinking its a duplicate?  Should I be putting it out of a void setup tag? as im unsure if this would then cause too many { brackets...

```
/* Question 1 */

int twoNumbers(){
int a = 30;
int b = 20;
 if (a > b) {println(a+b);}
  println("The sum of a and b is sum");
  int sum;
  sum = a+b;
  println(sum);
}
```

Any help would be massively helpful in getting this and the other questions done :)

Thanks!!

Comment: Use the method signature like in your assignment: `public static int twoNumbers(int a,int b)` and don't create new variables with the same names. Just use those variables. Also show us your main method, where you call this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also your function is not returning a value, which will give you an error. It looks like you are confusing things. Either declare it a void or return a value of declared type (that last is what your assignment calls for). Either way a function, or a method, needs to be called to execute, and you are not calling it! So the code inside your the function is not being run!!
The following:

```
void imAMethod()
{
  println("hello");
}
```

It is a valid method, but will do nothing, you need to call it, like:

```
imAMethod();// calling your method

void imAMethod()
{
  println("hello");
}
```

But this won't work also, will give you the error **"It looks like you're mixing "active" and "static" modes"**. Thats because to use a function in Processing you need to have at least a setup() method in the sketch, so:

```
 void setup()
{
  imAMethod();
}//end of setup

void imAMethod()
{
println("hello");
}
```

will work as expected.

But you need a function, so as Jesper pointed you will have to do something like:

```
int a = 30; // those are global variables to pass to your function
int b = 20;
void setup()// this is a builtin basic Processing method
 {
   //call your function 
   println("The sum of " + a + " and " + b + " is "+ twoNumbers(a, b));
 }

int twoNumbers(int a, int b)
{ 
//do your math and tests here
return result;
}
```

There is another thing not clear in the assignment. A function **must** return something, so it is not clear what the function should return if **a** is not greater than **b**. You will have to handle this case, or compiler will complain. You may want to move this test out of the function to make things easier, like:

```
if (a < b)
println("The sum of " + a + " and " + b + " is "+ twoNumbers(a, b));//call your function
else
println(a + " is smaller than " + b);
```

and in the function just do the sum. But this may be not what the assignment requires... Anyway you will need to return something even if **a** is not greater than **b**. Note that the printing to console can be done inside the function also.

Hummm, re reading the assignment a think what is expected is: Aways return the sum, and just print if **a** is greater than **b**, which makes more sense and is easier, something like:

```
int twoNUmbers(int a, int b)
{
 if (a < b){/*print the string*/}
 return a + b;
}
```

Just a note for jlordo. In Processing.org you don't have a main, or better, it is transparent/hidden from user. Processing is like a "dialect" of java. So the code above would run as it is. There are two basic builtin functions: setup() and draw(). If the user do not use none of them the IDE will warps it in a setup() function, that will call the main() somewhere else. It will run once. Draw() instead loops forever.

Answer (score 1):

> 'Write a function called twoNumbers(int a,int b) which takes in two parameters a and b.

That's not what your code looks like. Your method `twoNumbers` doesn't take two parameters `a` and `b`. Your code should start like this (exactly as mentioned in the assignment):

```
int twoNumbers(int a, int b) {
```

Remove the next two lines, `int a = 30;` and `int b = 20;`. Those lines declare two local variables named `a` and `b`. You should use the `a` and `b` that are passed in as parameters instead.

This also looks wrong:

```
if (a > b) {println(a+b);}
println("The sum of a and b is sum");
```

Carefully look at what the assignment says:

> If a is greater than b, then the two numbers are added together and the string 'the sum of a and b is sum' is displayed in the console window, where a and b and the sum are the values of a, b and their sum.

That's not what your code is doing. Take it step by step, carefully think about what is meant in the assignment.